# Unclear if my iPhone is has a carrier lock or not

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, unlock, sim

I have a very old iPhone 6 that I bought locked from Verizon. I'm trying to understand whether it still has a carrier lock on it, or whether I could bring my own SIM from a carrier that is not Verizon.

When I go to `Settings -> General -> About`, it shows `Carrier: Not Available.`

According to [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/793677/how-to-tell-if-your-iphone-is-unlocked/),

> If you see "No Sim Restrictions," then your iPhone is unlocked. If it says "SIM Locked" (or something similar), then your iPhone is locked to a particular carrier.

So what does `Carrier: Not Available` mean? Is there a way for me to determine whether my phone is carrier locked before buying another SIM?

[This article](https://www.verizon.com/support/device-unlocking-policy/)  implies that it should be unlocked, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's likely an "expired" SIM card. Call Verizon and ask them to unlock it, they will need some info off the phone, mostly related to the SIM card, but readily available. I used to do this all the time with AT&T phones at my previous job. I'd bet Verizon will do it too.